# Unixware 2.1.3 reset root password

Tags: root, password-recovery

I have been working on this problem for several days and cannot find any other suggestions on-line.

I have an old Lucent server running a proprietary Unixware 2.1.3 that I want to access but do not know any of the passwords. By building a new install of 2.1.3 on a spare disk I have built my emergency boot diskettes and can boot and mount the old hard drive and edit the files. However, when I remove the hash from the /etc/shadow file:

```
root::10630::::::
daemon:NP:6445::::::
bin:NP:6445::::::  .....
```

The system still wants a password for root. Just Pressing Enter doesn't work.

I have also tried setting the /etc/passwd file to:

```
root::0:3:0000-Admin(0000):/:/usr/bin/ksh
daemon:x:1:12:0000-Admin(0000):/:
bin:x:2:2:0000-Admin(0000):/usr/bin:
```

with the same result.

Experimenting on the new install drive I get the same results, however on the new install I can log in as root and run "passwd -d root" and the system behaves as expected and does not prompt me for a password at login.

If it has any relevance, I notice that the /etc directory contains shadow, oshadow (which appears to be a backup of shadow) and shadow.em that contains entries for root, bin and sys. Ditto with the passed file. I have tried editing these files too, but with no success.

Finally, I tried editing the home directory for root in the passed file on the new install but when I logged in it made no difference. Is it possible that the system is using an alternate to passwd, and if so how do I determine which file it is?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From a tek-tips post: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1204328

The boot floppys must match the Intuity software release.
To reset the root password do the following:

MACH 3 & 4
•    Bring Intuity up with the emergency boot floppy installed.
•    When prompted for keyboard type, type 1 
•    Screen will then say "If you would like a host bus adapter loaded from a floppy, insert it now and type yes"
•    Insert the HBA floppy and type yes .
NOTE: You must type the word yes or no, not y or n
•    Screen will again ask for hba diskette- remove diskette and press 
•    A # Prompt will then appear, type passwd root 
•    Enter password but do not use the password that you will actually want to use.
•    Type exit and press cnt-alt-delete when prompted making sure there are no diskettes in drive.
•    After the Intuity is up, log in with new password and you will be immediately prompted to change password.
•    Put in password that you actually want.
*NOTE: An ACCX (AYC22) card in the system can cause the floppy to not be read. Remove it and proceed.

MACH 5
•    If the system is currently running, bring it down.
•    Insert boot floppy #1 into the floppy drive.
•    Boot the machine.
•    Insert boot floppy #2 into the floppy drive when requested and press 
•    When the system displays the menu that asks if you want to "load the system, access the shell or reboot", select access the shell .
•    At the shell prompt type: SHBOOT 
•    Navigate the menus that select the hardware (5P, 40P or 100P) and disk configuration (IDE or SCSI) for the machine you are recovering. This process loads the correct device drivers for access to the disk(s) on your machine.
•    Mount the root filesystem; type: mount   /dev/root   /mnt 
•    Change the password; type: chroot  /mnt  /usr/bin/passwd  root
•    Enter the new password

You shouldn't need root though, stick with SA or VM